# How do you obtain pets in Sims freeplay for iOS?

Tags: the-sims-freeplay

I was playing Sims freeplay on my iPod yesterday and got a dog from god knows where. How do you obtain additional pets in Sims freeplay for the iPod (in addition to the pet you receive at the beginning)?

Answer (score 2):

> You need to build the Pet Store on the town map, and then tap on it to enter the Pet Store screen.

[Source](https://help.ea.com/article/the-sims-freeplay-pets-faq)